# WXPython Video MediaCtrl custom over Button

Tags: python, wxpython

I am a newbie to wxpython. I am unable to overlap panels. In general, it is easy to do it with two or multiple panels but if one of the panels has the MediaCtrl container playing video on the full display screen, then any other panel is not visible above it. I tried with the panel.Raise() method but still, it is not working.
All I am looking forward is to overlap a dummy panel with a StaticText over the videoPlayer panel. In the below code the green box is coming below the MediaCtrl controller. I have to somehow bring the bannel panel above the video panel. I went through a lot question but all i could get is to use .Raise() whihc is not working in my case.

```
import wx
import wx.media
import os


########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent_size = parent.GetClientSize()
        self.init_view()

    def init_view(self):

        #self.SetDimensions(0, 0, wx.GetDisplaySize().width, wx.GetDisplaySize().height)
        self.SetDimensions(0, 0, 50,50)
        self.text_view = wx.StaticText(self, size=(1020, 40), pos=(10, 10), label="Some Label")
        self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self)

        # from wx.animate import AnimationCtrl
        # self.text_view.write("ABDS")
        self.settings_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Settings")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.settings_button_clicked, self.settings_btn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.on_panel_clicked)
        print(os.path.exists("SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4"))
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4")) + "/SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4"
        if not self.mc.Load(path):
            print("unable to load video")
        else:
            self.mc.SetInitialSize()
            self.mc.Play()


    def on_panel_clicked(self, event):
        print("panel clicked...")
        if self.settings_btn.IsShown():
            self.settings_btn.Hide()
        else:
            self.settings_btn.Show()

    def settings_button_clicked(self, event):
        print("Settings Btn Clicked...")


class BannerPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        self.SetDimensions(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.Raise()
        #self.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        # wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test Maximize", size=wx.Size(1100, 700), style=wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        self.videoPlayerPanel = MyPanel(self)
        self.bannerPanel = BannerPanel(self)
        self.Show()
        # self.videoPlayerPanel.mc.Lower()
        self.bannerPanel.Raise()
        # print(self.GetClientSize())
        # self.Maximize(True)
        # self.initGUI()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    # frame.ShowFullScreen(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a sizer, then adding the panels to the sizer.  This should ensure that the panels can be manipulated and kept in the right place.  A good read on it https://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp
What you can do is edit:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
""""""

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    """"""
    # wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test Maximize",     size=wx.Size(1100, 700), style=wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
    self.videoPlayerPanel = MyPanel(self)
    self.bannerPanel = BannerPanel(self)

    self.vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.vsizer.Add(self.videoPlayerPanel, 0)
    self.videoPlayerPanel.SetSizer(self.vsizer)
    self.videoPlayerPanel.Show()

    self.bsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.bsizer.Add(self.bannerPanel, 0)
    self.bannerPanel.SetSizer(self.bsizer)
    self.bannerPanel.Raise()
    self.bannerPanel.Show()
```

With a bit of tweaking, you can set the panel sizes and their location on the frame, have a look at the link for a really good explanation.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for replying. But with BoxSizer in the vertical layout, both the panels are coming in a vertical layout whereas I am trying to bring the bannerPanel above the videoPlayerPanel.

Comment: I have edited my reply, I think that they may need to be in a separate sizer, then raise the second one.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for looking into this. I tried with the above code and ideally your code should work with the panels with widgets like statictext, etc but I think the issue has to do something in specific with the wx.media.MediaCtrl which I am using for the video player and somehow it is not allowing any other raised view/panel to come above it.

Comment: Yea, having trouble with the mediactrl.  The only other way I could think to have a go would be to create a second transparent window(frame) over the top with just the text showing.  Thats what I am trying here, but ensuring the window is in the right place may prove to be tricky.  My other thought would be - is it a static video, i.e not streamed?  you could overlay the text first using a different process, like openCV.  I can't remember much, but it is something like:

Answer (score 1):

@rohitranjan, this answer was too long for a comment, I'm having trouble with the mediactrl.  The only other way I could think to have a go would be to create a second transparent window(frame) over the top with just the text showing.  Thats what I am trying here, but ensuring the window is in the right place may prove to be tricky.  My other thought would be - is it a static video, i.e not streamed?  you could overlay the text first using a different process, like openCV.  I can't remember much, but it is something like: `import cv2` and `cv2.puText(frame, text, position)`.  You may need `cv2.VideoWriter()` and `cv2.VideoCapture()` too.  That's what I would look into next, have the text overlaid before wx imports and plays the video.  openly searching opencv, video text overlay should prove useful.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the suggestion, I did try to paint a text like https://wiki.wxpython.org/VerySimpleDrawing but even this is not visible over the video. I also tried raising the textview and lowering the video player view but still, somehow the video player view is coming at the top hiding all the other widgets. I could not find a proper article connecting OpenCV with wxpython frame/panel. If you could guide me to a website having that, it would help me try it. I guess will have to look into mediactrl a little deeper to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have something working here, I'm adding text to the video first, then just using wx to play the video.  So essentially, 'pre-editing' the video.  It is not mega fast initially, depending on your video size, but it makes the process so much easier, as you are just playing a single video.  I'm using MoviePy, which imports the video, adds text over the top and then exports it to the same directory.  I added this to your original code at the top

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip("your_video.mp4")
txt_overlay = TextClip("test text", fontsize=50, color='white')
clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", codec='mpeg4')
```

Then from here, you can run the rest of your code using 'output.mp4' in a single window.  It may not be exactly what you need, as it involves a little time processing the file initially, but if it isn't a stream, then it works quite nicely.  I'm not sure what system you are running, but here is the link to the MoviePy module. https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/crash_course/crash_course.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for introducing me to MoviePy. It indeed does work the way you say it should. But the issue is that there are lots of other widgets that I have to put above the video panel and also the text in my case will keep on changing with some other trigger. So you see somehow I have to get the panel over above the video panel.